# Can't use Name from lookup field in formula

Tags: formula, formula-field, lookup

I want to define a formula field to have the value of the Name field of a lookup field. I tried something like this:

```
Lead__r.Name
```

where "Lead" is a lookup field pointing to a lead. However, the formula builder complains that "Name is not a field". When I use "Insert Field", and click on the Lead lookup field, it shows me all the expected fields on Leads *except* Name. Is there something special about Name? What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Lead's don't have a Name field like most other objects, the only way to get the full name is to manually combine the FisrtName and LastName in your formula:

```
Lead__r.FirstName & " " & Lead__r.LastName
```

Comment: Thank you. In that case, what is the meaning of the "Name" field documented at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.226.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm?

Comment: Salesforce uses that field when displaying leads (in relationship fields or list views etc.), and the Name field is accessible in code, it's just not accessible in formula fields